# Represent Query Results as new Table

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have difficulty to construct right query currently i have two Queries

Query 1.

```
SELECT $TOTAL
LET $CORE = (SELECT FROM SOMETHING_1 WHERE SOMECONDITION_1),
$SOURCE= (SELECT FROM SOMETHING_2 WHERE SOMECONDITION_2),
$TOTAL = UNIONALL($CORE.A , $CORE.B ,$SOURCE.C)
```

As A Result i receive: 
**[A1, A2 , B1 , B2 ,C1 , C2]**

Query 2.

```
SELECT $CORE.A , $CORE.B ,$SOURCE.C
LET $CORE = (SELECT FROM SOMETHING_1 WHERE SOMECONDITION_1),
$SOURCE= (SELECT FROM SOMETHING_2 WHERE SOMECONDITION_2)
```

As A Result i receive

```
**[A1, A2 ],[ B1 , B2] ,[C1 , C2]**
```

Which query should i need two use if i want to receive following result:

> [A1, B1 , C1 ],[ A2 , B2 , C2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information like database structure, purpose of the query ... Thx in advance

Comment: This is a simplified version of the DB , Lets say the first CORE.A and CORE.B are returning dates and  SOURCE returning a string, I would like to iterate on results for further use and i need to use them as triple A1, B1 , C1 etc..

Comment: To have a result like you want you depends on the query, for example which kind of a condition your query should match? Do you want to execute the query on a class,or it has to across edges? Are there some specific properties to return? How many classes do you have?

Comment: For a purpose of example all the tables are rational , lets say that table SOMETHING_1 has 3 columns , creationTime[date] , modificationTime[date], userName[string]. SOMETHING_2 has 2 columns mail[string] and userName[string]. I want to see in a new table following results  creationTime[date] , modificationTime[date], mail[string]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select expand($c)
LET $a = (select creationTime, modificationTime from SOMETHING_1 where SOMECONDITION_1),
$b = (select columns_mail from SOMETHING_2 where SOMECONDITION_2),
$c = unionall($a,$b)
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I have to say it is not always working , sometimes i recieve content of query $a and afterwards $b although they have same @rid   , is there any addional contion that i am missing ?